# Cannot view the wsdl document jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, java-11

I am trying the deploy a web service using an annotated class and Jax-WS. I am deploying it using maven.

The class is just an example program that I have used previously with Java 8. I have recently moved to Java 11 and it does not work any more.  I am aware of all the changes with Java 11 and have added a number of different sets of dependencies (I had success previously using com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.1 and javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1 with Java 9).

Can I use Jax-WS in this way with Java 11, or do I need to switch to a top-down approach?

Thanks in advance!

The code:

```
package quote;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;


@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use= Use.LITERAL)
public class StockPrice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9000/quote", new StockPrice());
    }

    private Map<String, Double> prices = new TreeMap<>();
    {
        prices.put("IBM", 143.79);
        prices.put("GOOGL", 1209.70);
        prices.put("MSFT", 137.44);
        prices.put("FB", 175.25);
        prices.put("TWTR", 40.22);
    }

    @WebMethod public double GetStockQuote(String StockName) {
        Double price = prices.get(StockName);
        return price == null ? -1:price;
    }
}
```

The pom.xml file:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>    

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>quote.StockPrice</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to fix this one myself.  It seems that the problem with with the way Web Services are published - the `endpoint.publish(...)` method does not work as previously.

To solve the problem, I had to use the following `main()` method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new StockPrice());
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 5);
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
        HttpContext context = server.createContext("/quote");

        endpoint.publish(context);
        server.start();
    }
```

I got this from the "Getting Started with Metro" tutorial: https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/getting-started/getting-started.html#basma-building

Specifically, I had to download the "From-Java example" code base which included this as a "optional" alternative approach to deploying endpoints.